# Как реализовать подсветку синтаксиса в RichTextView?

Tags: c#, алгоритм, winforms

Решил прикрутить подсветку синтаксиса в редакторе. Есть массив слов которые нужно сделать жирными и синенькими. Задачу стал решать в лоб:

- При вводе символа, производим анализ текста
- Если встретили нужное слово из списка, то назначаем ему указанный стиль.

Встретились проблемы: анализ происходит долго (ключевых слов порядка 200, текст может быть объемным, содержать порядка 1000 строк), заметно мелькание выделенного текста (чтобы назначить стиль в RichTextView приходится выделить текст, применить стиль). Ну и при переформатировании происходят глюки, стиль к выбранному фрагменту не применяется или применяется не к полному выделенному фрагменту.

Подскажите оптимальный вариант, как следует правильно реализовывать цветовую раскраску ключевых слов?

Answer (score 2):

Взять уже готовый контрол с подсветкой:

- [ScintillaNET](http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/) - только он не managed а нативный
- [Colored TextBox](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/161871/Fast-Colored-TextBox-for-syntax-highlighting)
- [Редактор из старых версий #develop](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30936/Using-ICSharpCode-TextEditor)